# Presto logging to logstash

Tags: presto

Is there a way to push logs from presto cluster(co-ordinator and worker nodes) to some centralized logging system like logstash ?

Thanks,
Dheeraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are server logs you are talking about, you can always have filebeat tailing the logs and sending them to centralized logstash instance. This is the typical usecase of logstash.

Comment: Thanks Vijay, will try using filebeat